# Reverse Engineering a Vehicle Identification Number (VIN) encoding

Tags: encryption, encodings, hash-functions

Not sure if this is the right place so please point me to the right place if needed.

---

I have an input of a VIN (Vehicle Identification Number) number with 17 characters, each character is either an uppercase letter or number.

The input is then encoded into 24 signed integers, the integers go from -128 to +127.

There doesn't seem to be any direct linear relationship between the two.

Does anyone know what this encoding might be? Or, how I should go about trying to reverse engineering it?

---

An example is:
Input: 1D8HB58D04F177301
Output:-2|-72|-11|-2|18|100|-69|15|93|120|15|-97|-35|52|85|-114|53|-123|-1|-101|-38|125|-100|113

I have access to a dataset mapping the inputs to outputs and also a tool that converts an encoding (24 integers) into a VIN

---

Inexperienced with this so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes that's correct, also edited the post to clarify

Comment: net is full of vin decoders  your 1dxxxxxx vin is  2004 DODGE Durango says  https://www.decodethevin.com/   Wikipedia has lots of info on what is what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number

Comment: Just to clarify, the idea isn't to decode what a VIN represents. Instead, it's to understand how the VIN is being encoded into that 24 number representation in the dataset I am working with

Comment: well analyze the tool that you have in hand with whatever tool you are comfortable with say radare / ghidra / ida / windbg / ollydbg / gdb   as is this is too broad to attempt to answer  narrow down the scope

Comment: Unfortunately the tool is hosted therefore the actual logic is happening server-side. Really I was checking to see if there was some obvious manipulation of the bits that would yield the encoding